# How do you call a program used to design a level from sprites?

Tags: sprites, terminology

How do you call the concept or the process of designing sprites in 2d graphics program, assembling them in that program and exporting them for your game?

I need that kind of program but I can't think of the correct terminology to search for it.

Comment: Hey, welcome to gamedev.se! Sorry, I butchered your question: asking for programs that does X or Z is off-topic here (i.e. "What technology to use"), but you can ask about the terminology that would help you find more about it, I reworded the question that way.

Comment: It really depends on how you plan to make the game. I never knew this was a thing (unless you are referring to level editors that are included in game engines). If you make a game with opengl for example, you can create a level with a graphics program like Gimp or Photoshop.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like what are looking for is a *level editor* (or *map editor*). There are various kinds of level editing tools; we often qualify them by the type of data they edit.

For example you’re probably looking for (based on some info that was edited out of the question) a *tile-based* or *tile map* editor such as [Tiled](http://www.mapeditor.org).

Also note that you don't *need* a level editor, necessarily. Plenty of people make tile-based games just using text editors to define the level data (using characters: `#` represents a wall, `.` a floor, `S` a character spawn, or whatever).